# getting error while trying to find sat or sun using php

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to find a day who provided by the user and I am getting error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79 bytes)

```
$days = $array('saturday','sunday'); // it's dynamic array

if(sizeof($days)>0) {

  foreach($days as $key => $value) {
    $start  = strtotime("today"); // your start/end dates here
    $end    = strtotime("today +6 years");
    $friday = strtotime(strtolower($value), $start);

    while($friday <= $end) {
      //$daysbox[] = date("Y-m-d", $friday);                
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Is the above your code, exactly your code, all your code, nothing but your code, exactly the way it is written including all the comments?

Comment: Which line does it throw the error at exactly? Is the array info accurate or not - what does it contain?

Comment: it's not mine i got for google, but i am trying to change according to my requirement.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Allowed memory size, while loop throws error

Comment: Where on google did you get this exactly?

Comment: yeah here is original code $start = strtotime("today"); // your start/end dates here
$end = strtotime("today +1 years");
$friday = strtotime("wednesday", $start);
while($friday <= $end) {
    echo "wednesday=", date("d m Y", $friday), "<br>";
    echo "sat=", date("d m Y", strtotime("+1 days", $friday)), "<br>";    
    echo "sun=", date("d m Y", strtotime("+2 days", $friday)), "<br>";
 echo('<hr>');
    $friday = strtotime("+1 weeks", $friday);
}

Comment: i just implement if statement and foreach look according to my requirement

Comment: Yeah well, that's not how your code looks now, is it? You need to at least copy the `$friday = strtotime("+1 weeks", $friday);` into your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($friday <= $end) {
    $daysbox[] = date("Y-m-d", $friday);                
}
```

Assuming it crashes in that way when that line is not commented out: (Otherwise you would have an infinite loop, but it would not crash with the error you described).

You're not changing `$friday`, you're not changing `$end`. This means that if the condition is true once, it will continue to stay true. All you do is add something to an array. If you do this an infinite number of times, sooner or later you will run out of memory.

You probably want to change the `$friday` variable inside your while-loop, like this:

```
while($friday <= $end) {
    $friday = strtotime("+1 weeks", $friday);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely nothing going on in your while loop.  Your code is going to hit that while loop and you're right smack into an infinite loop.